# Ruby run two processes, output results to terminal, and end safely

Tags: ruby, multithreading, process

In Ruby, I'm running a system("command here") that is constantly watching changes for files, similar to tail.  I'd like my program to continue to run and not halt at the system() call.  Is there a way in Ruby to create another process so both can run independently, output results to the terminal, and then when you exit the program all processes the application created are removed?

Comment: Do you want to kill all your child processes when the program is exiting or do you want to wait for the children to finish on their own before exiting?

Comment: kill all child processes when the program is exiting.  Both processes are watching for changes in files so neither will actually finish.

Answer (score 2):

Just combine [`spawn`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Process.html#M001282) and [`waitall`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Process.html#M001291):

```
spawn 'sleep 6'
spawn 'sleep 8'
Process.waitall
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to use [`system`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Kernel.html#M001441) as that waits for the process to complete. You could use [`spawn`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Kernel.html#M001442) instead and then [wait](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Process.html#M001287) for the processes (to avoid zombies). Then, when you want to exit, send a SIGTERM to your spawned processes. You could also use [`fork`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Process.html#M001281) to launch your child processes but `spawn` is probably easier if you're using external programs.

You could also use process groups instead of tracking all the process IDs, then a single `Process.kill('TERM', -process_group_id)` call would take care of things. Your child processes should end up in the same process group but there is [`Process.setpgid`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Process.html#M001298) if you need it.

Here's an example that uses `fork` (easier to get it all wrapped in one package that way).

```
def launch(id, sleep_for)
    pid = Process.fork do
        while(true)
            puts "#{id}, pgid = #{Process.getpgid(Process.pid())}, pid = #{Process.pid()}"
            sleep(sleep_for)
        end
    end
    # No zombie processes please.
    Process.wait(pid, Process::WNOHANG)
    pid
end

# These just forward the signals to the whole process group and
# then immediately exit.
pgid = Process.getpgid(Process.pid())
Signal.trap('TERM') { Process.kill('TERM', -pgid); exit }
Signal.trap('INT' ) { Process.kill('INT',  -pgid); exit }

launch('a', 5)
launch('b', 3)
while(true)
    puts "p, pgid = #{Process.getpgid(Process.pid())}, pid = #{Process.pid()}"
    sleep 2
end
```

If you run that in one terminal and then kill it from another (using the shell's [`kill`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/kill.html) command)you'll see that the children are also killed. If you remove the "forward this signal to the whole process group" `Signal.trap` stuff, then a simple SIGTERM will leave the children still running.

All of this assumes that you're working on some sort of Unixy system (such as Linux or OSX), YMMV anywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

One more vote for using Spawn.  We use it in Production a lot and it's very stable.